# ArcMap Basic License - Create exterior boundary around polyline features based on centerline layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, polygon-creation, boundaries, basic-license-level

I have access to ArcGIS with a basic license at work. I have been tasked with creating a boundary outline of every route polyline feature whose shape is also based along the city street network base layer. Aside from manually tracing polygons for a boundary or selecting the base line layer to symbolize one, is there any quicker method to facilitate this?

I've attached an example to provide a visual. The red line features are an example of what our routes look like, and the advanced looking blue boundary (Courtesy of my advanced Paint skills) shows what I'd like to create:

[image: Example]

Comment: You have some attribute identifying each route?

Comment: Yes, so for this feature I could symbolize each route by "beat." There are 10 different beats within this pictured layer.

Comment: Try Modelbuilder with "Iterate feature selection" selecting by `beat` then Buffer with dissolve. Or select manually and buffer with dissolve. Then merge all outputs

Comment: I think I was unclear in my comment. For this particular example, I don't need to draw a boundary around each beat. They just want a boundary around every beat within the red polyline pictured above. The further complication is that they want the boundary to run on the base street network rather than being its own independent shape. Please let me know if that is not clear.

Comment: Your model is not clear. Why it is curvy along West side and straight at North?

Comment: Hi Felix, that was just a manual drawing of mine to highlight what I was generally looking for. I found a manual workaround for this in the end utilizing some existing polygons that I modified to encapsulate the extent of the routes.